# Issues with Prisma: The database schema is not empty. Read more about how to baseline an existing production database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, next.js, prisma

I am having issues with Prisma and getting this error: The database schema is not empty. Read more about how to baseline an existing production database.

When I have made changes I usually just do npx prisma db push but this causes fields to be erased if I do not have a @default. I want to migrate my changes that but I am always getting that error.

I have already ran npx prisma migrate dev --name init and have a migrations folder named 20230915233627_init.

What are the right commands to succsesfully make changes to my schema?

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["jsonProtocol"]
}

datasource db {
  provider          = "postgresql"
  url               = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL")
  directUrl         = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING")
  shadowDatabaseUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING")
}

model News {
  approved     Boolean      @default(false)
  id           String       @id @default(cuid())
  title        String
  headline     String
  summary      String
  article      String
  image        String?
  photoCredit  String?
  category     Category?    @default(POLITICS)
  originalUrl  String
  originalBias OriginalBias
  createdAt    DateTime     @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt    DateTime     @default(now()) @updatedAt @map("updated_at") 
  test         String       @default("")
}

enum Category {
  POLITICS
  SPORTS
  TECHNOLOGY
  ENTERTAINMENT
  HEALTH
  SCIENCE
  BUSINESS
  WORLD
  ECONOMY
  LIFESTYLE
}

enum OriginalBias {
  LEFT
  CENTER
  RIGHT
}
```